# Can anyone please explain how this is working?

Tags: java, arrays, foreach

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3,4,1};
for (int n: a) {
    a[n] = 0;
}
for (int n: a) {
    System.out.print(n);
}
```

This for each loop showing something unexpected result when I make a all array elements 0.Instead of showing all '0' it is giving output something like '00301'.Not able to understand how this is working?

Comment: I'm trying in java but working of for each  loop is same in any language I think

Comment: It isn't C# and it isn't C++. Java maybe?  Do you know what language you're working in? Whatever it is, I'm pretty sure it isn't doing what you think it is. Note that you are iterating over an array and using the value of the array elements as indexes into the array. Make one of the initial values large (like, say, 10) and watch what happens

Comment: The code at line `a[n] = 0;` is incorrect. It won't make indexed elements to zero but it will make element at the index of current value to zero. 
Value of `n` will be `1, 2, 3, 4 , 1` inside iteration if  `a[n] = 0;` is not present. 
Try indexed based loop for setting array items to zero `for(int i=0; i<a.length;i++) {a[i]=0;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a[n] = 0;` is setting the `a[some_value_from_the_array]` to 0, not setting all the array elements to 0.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by the Oracle documentation, the java for-each loop hides the iterator, and gives you access to only the values in the iterable (array). Therefore, the for-each loop should not be used for mainupulating the original array, rather should be used for working with the data of the array.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html
If you want to manipulate the original array, your best bet is to use the conventional for loop.

Answer (score 1):

It's two for-each loops over the contents of an `int[]`.

Loop 1: for each `n` in `1, 2, 3, 4, 1` set the contents of the array to zero for indices 1, 0, 3, 0 and 1. Which you can see by changing it to

```
for (int n: a) {
    System.out.println(n);
    a[n] = 0;
}
```

Leaving the contents of `a` as `0, 0, 3, 0, 1` then

Loop 2: for each `n` in `0, 0, 3, 0, 1` print `n`.

Thus your program prints 00301.

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
for (int n: a)
```

`n` is the **value** of a particular index the array, **not the index** itself. So, you are basically setting 0 at index 1, 2, 3,4,1. Luckily there is no value greater than 4 (the length of the array) or negative number else you will get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException.

```
for (int i=0; i<a.length;i++){
  a[i] = 0;
}
```

Use the above code and you will get the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

If you print out what it does, you'll see for yourself:

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3,4,1};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
for (int n: a) {
    System.out.print("a[" + n + "] = 0;  ->  ");
    a[n] = 0;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
}
```

*Output*

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1]
a[1] = 0;  ->  [1, 0, 3, 4, 1]
a[0] = 0;  ->  [0, 0, 3, 4, 1]
a[3] = 0;  ->  [0, 0, 3, 0, 1]
a[0] = 0;  ->  [0, 0, 3, 0, 1]
a[1] = 0;  ->  [0, 0, 3, 0, 1]
```

Comment: @DevendraJadhav I wasn't trying to give you the *answer*, I was trying to show you how to get the answer yourself, so you won't have to ask again next time. --- *Give a Man a Fish, and You Feed Him for a Day. Teach a Man To Fish, and You Feed Him for a Lifetime*

Comment: Thank you so much sir for giving me a way to get an answer as a beginner that is the necessary thing for me